# How to assign empty value to input type number using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input type number. I want to set default value 1 if ng-model is null or empty or undefined. it works fine.
But on the same page, I have a submit button. on click of this button, I'm just returning false for some validation fail. But when it returns after validation fails. my dropdown (input type number) shows empty value. I check the value of ng-model, it's empty.

So if the value is not a proper number, I want it to set to 1 by default.

```
<input type="number" step="1" min="1" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? '': event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" id="train_n_file" 
                                          ng-init="item.n_fold = item.n_fold || 1" ng-model="item.n_fold" ng-disabled="item.train_select=='training_time_range'" style="margin-top: -2px;" class="input-div" value="{{1}}">


<md-button ng-click="schedule_event()" type=submit id="step-btn" class="build-model md-raised step-btn md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple"> Schedule </md-button>


 $scope.schedule_event = function () {
  if (some condition) {
      $scope.showAlert('Please pick schedule frequency.');
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: Why do you have that `onkeypress` in there? Setting `type="number"` prevents entry of non-numeric values. You also shouldn't have a `value` attribute if you're using `ng-model`. Sounds like most of this should be handled in your model or controller.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I was just trying everything to get it done

Comment: Try creating a directive which checks the `<input>` field value ,do the necessary validation and updates the `model` value of `<input>` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

This would do the trick. ng-init is used to initialize values for the ng-model.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('inputCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = undefined;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>plnkr</title>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-controller="inputCtrl">
        <input type="number" step="1" min="1" ng-model="item" ng-init="item = 10" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="inputCtrl.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Edited. Added variable to ng-init.

Comment: try by adding a submit button, try to reproduce the same scenario. u will get my question

Comment: Please provide a plunker with the scenario, we will get your question.